# Access parent column in subquery inner join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

```
SELECT p.id                      AS 'project_id', 
       p.hours                   AS 'budgeted_hours', 
       p.workedhours             AS 'worked_hours', 
       (SELECT Sum(tl.hours) AS total 
        FROM   tasks t 
               INNER JOIN tasklogs tl 
                       ON ( t.projects_id = 9000
                            AND tl.tasks_id = t.id ) 
        GROUP  BY t.projects_id) AS foo 
FROM   projects AS p 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND p.isactive = 1 
GROUP  BY p.id
```

This query works fine, except the project ID is hardcoded ( 9000  in the subquery ). I'm trying to replace `9000` with `projects.id` or when aliased, `p.id`. This results in a syntax error:

```
SELECT p.id                      AS 'project_id', 
       p.hours                   AS 'budgeted_hours', 
       p.workedhours             AS 'worked_hours', 
       (SELECT Sum(tl.hours) AS total 
        FROM   tasks t 
               INNER JOIN tasklogs tl 
                       ON ( t.projects_id = p.id
                            AND tl.tasks_id = t.id ) 
        GROUP  BY t.projects_id) AS foo 
FROM   projects AS p 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND p.isactive = 1 
GROUP  BY p.id
```

Which results in `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'p.id' in 'on clause'`. Also tried adding an `ON`:

```
SELECT   p.id          AS 'project_id', 
         p.hours       AS 'budgeted_hours', 
         p.workedhours AS 'worked_hours', 
         ( 
                    SELECT     Sum(tl.hours) AS total 
                    FROM       tasks t 
                    INNER JOIN tasklogs tl 
                    ON         ( 
                                          t.projects_id= p.id 
                               AND        tl.tasks_id=t.id ) 
                    GROUP BY   t.projects_id ) AS foo 
on t.projects_id = p.id
FROM     projects AS p 
WHERE    1=1 
AND      p.isactive = 1 
GROUP BY p.id
```

Which apparently is wrong as well. I'm just not grokking how to access `p.id`?

Comment: You should be joining to the sub query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a MySQL maven, but have you tried this for your subquery?

```
                SELECT     Sum(tl.hours) AS total 
                FROM       tasks t 
                INNER JOIN tasklogs tl 
                ON         tl.tasks_id = t.id
                WHERE      t.projects_id = p.id
                GROUP BY   t.projects_id
```

Comment: Jeez, not sure what I was thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT p.id                      AS 'project_id', 
       p.hours                   AS 'budgeted_hours', 
       p.workedhours             AS 'worked_hours', 
       (SELECT Sum(tl.hours) AS total 
        FROM   tasks t 
               INNER JOIN tasklogs tl 
                       ON ( tl.tasks_id = t.id ) 
        GROUP  BY t.projects_id
        HAVING t.projects_id = p.id) AS foo 
FROM   projects AS p 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND p.isactive = 1 
GROUP  BY p.id
```